# 2003 Honda CRV oil leaks

Tags: honda, oil-leak, crv

2003 Honda CRV with 117,000 miles. At last oil change in April @ 116,000 miles at the dealer they noticed a fluid leak at timing cover inspection plate and resealed the plate. They also noted that I needed to change the compliance bushings so I just had that done 2 weeks ago.

A couple days after that work was completed I noticed an oil leak under the passenger side front end. It only leaked after driving, not after sitting overnight etc. I took it back to the dealer who wanted $ to diagnose the issue and the mechanic said it looked like it was in the same area as the inspection plate that they sealed in April.

Tired of the crappy customer service at the dealer, I took it to another shop  I trust who used dye to diagnose the leak for less $ than the dealer and they said the leak was located at the VTC Oil Control Solenoid. I gave them the go ahead to replace that and then I get a call that now there is a leak at the crankshaft seal.

No indicator lights have come one at all, I drive < 50 miles/week, and I've done all the regular maintenance on time since purchasing new including changing the timing belt at 105000 miles.

So, I'm trying to understand why the oil leaks all of a sudden. Is it likely just a case of a wandering oil leak due to old gaskets etc. or could the leaks be related to the compliance bushing repair (such as something getting knocked or damaged during the repair) or the timing cover inspection plate repair back in April?

What questions should I be asking the mechanics at this point before doing any more repairs?

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is that the engine's crank case ventilation system is blocked.  This can cause a pressure increase inside the block which can then force oil out of the oil seals.

Comment: K24 and K20 series engines were notorious for the PCV valve and IACV maintenance. I’d look there as well.